# iOS - Unable to get push notification sound when app is already performing video call or playing any video using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, avplayer

In one of mobile application, we have an audio call feature using WebRTC & playing video using HLS Streaming.

The application also has a push notification feature with default sound. We are getting push notification properly & always get default sound when it arrives.

But we are not getting sound/vibration in the below scenario :

**Scenario 1:**

- We play the video using HLS streaming with AVPlayer & push
  notification arrived.
- We got the notification **but the sound was not
  played by iOS.**

**Scenario 2:**

- We perform audio call using WebRTC & push notification arrived.
- We got the notification **but the sound was not played by iOS.**

Please guide if anyone has faced the same issue & found any solution for the same.